# How to register a domain for a beginner?

Tags: domain-registration

I've never registered a .com , .net like domain before, and I would like to do some research before doing so.

1. I currently have a ruby on rails app running Heroku. Is there anything special I have to do prior to registering domain on my ruby on rails app at all? Or is it as easy as just inserting my current Heroku address to mask it with another .com or .net name?
2. Is there some special features I should look for registering domain? Or is it typical for domain seller to just sell domain names only?
3. Any recommendations on sellers?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Since you are using Heroku, start with their [custom domain documentation](http://docs.heroku.com/custom-domains). Actually, that is really rather comprehensive, so I'd stop with them too.
2. You have hosting already. You might want to find one that will do email hosting for you (although I don't know how well that will play with Zerigo DNS, so you might need to use your domain registrar's DNS service).
3. Given the horror stories I've head about Godaddy — not them. I've been happy with Easily.co.uk.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few details at the bottom of this page http://www.arailsdemo.com/posts/9.

I was also in your situation and never bought a domain name before. I went with namecheap.com and haven't had any problems.

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to purchase a domain name from anyone. (GoDaddy is very popular) and set it up to point to your Heroku account.

Answer (score 0):

The most valuable features you are to have after domain registration is domain transfer, domain DNS change, access to your own domain control panel where you can update your records and contact details.