# How to register a domain for a beginner?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, domains

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to register a domain for a beginner?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/7375/how-to-register-a-domain-for-a-beginner)

I've never registered a .com , .net like domain before, and I would like to do some research before doing so.

1. I currently have a ruby on rails app running Heroku. Is there anything special I have to do prior to registering domain on my ruby on rails app at all? Or is it as easy as just inserting my current Heroku address to mask it with another .com or .net name?
2. Is there some special features I should look for registering domain? Or is it typical for domain seller to just sell domain names only?
3. Any recommendations on sellers?

Thank you.

Comment: Stack overflow is really designed for questions about programming.  You'll get a lot more useful questions at one of the other StackExchange sites.  Try webmasters.stackexchange.com